# How to check if the input is a character and show that it is "invalid input", otherwise it will run as is

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h.>
#include<locale>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    int b;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    char a = b;

    if (a >= 'a' || a <= 'z' || a >= 'A' || a <= 'Z' )
    {
        printf("Invalid input");
    }
    if(int b=a || b<=0)
    {
        printf("It's a Negative number");
    }
    else if(int b=a || b>0)
    {
        printf("It's a Positive number");
    }
    else if(int b=a && b==0)
    {
        printf("It's a Zero");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add code copy and pase it in the editor, select it and use the {} button to form a code block or press ctrl-k

Comment: Ok. Thank you for that info. Can you help me with this one? I just need to add an if block to tell the user that his/her input is invalid, as the program can only get numerical inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean logic is close, but slightly misinterpreted.

You will need to check values between a `AND` z `OR` A `AND` Z for invalid input.

Once you know the ASCII representation doesn't encode a letter you can then convert to an int and do regular math logic to check if its positive, negative, etc...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    char b;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%c",&b);
    // checking ASCII value of b isn't between a AND z OR A AND Z
    if ((b >=  'a' && b <= 'z') || (b >=  'A' && b <= 'Z'))
    {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
    } else {
        // convert ASCII representation to the actual int it encodes
        int a = b - '0';
        if(a<0)
        {
            printf("It's a Negative number\n");
        }
        else if(a>0)
        {
            printf("It's a Positive number\n");
        }
        else if(a==0)
        {
            printf("It's a Zero\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's just perfect!